# What is the iron:router 1.0 equivalent of this.setLayout() and this.lookupLayoutTemplate()?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Calling `this.setLayout()` or `this.lookupLayoutTemplate()`, for instance in this example:

https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/655

gives:

```
Exception in callback of async function: TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `this.setLayout` is now `this.layout()`.
- `this.lookupLayoutTemplate` is now `Router.lookupLayoutTemplate`

Also take note that onBeforeAction now has three arguments:

```
Router.onBeforeAction(function(req, res, next) {  

  next(); // or this.next(); 
          // still the same as pause().. 
          // you MUST call next so the route renders.
});
```

Comment: Any idea why `Router.lookupLayoutTemplate` returns `undefined` when visiting index? `Router.map -> this.route('/', {name: 'index', layoutTemplate: 'headered'})`

Comment: Try `Router.map -> this.route('index', {path: '/', layoutTemplate: 'headered'})` instead.

Comment: Still undefined, both in `onBeforeAction` and after page has loaded.

Comment: Filed bug. Simplified example: http://meteorpad.com/pad/82MLzBqYZYcx7NkR8/Copy%20of%20Leaderboard

Comment: You're right. I think the issue is caused by the actual on-creation options not being passed properly from configuration context to instance/run time context. [You can see what I mean here]. (http://imgur.com/xFBLXFB.png) It is easily overridden by `Router.configure` but it would not be the desired output. However a work around is to just store `this.options.layout._template` somewhere before modifying the layout if in case you want to revert to it at some time.